# Yii filter CHtml::dropDownList group results

Tags: yii

I am using CHtml::dropDownList as filter for one column in Yii

```
array(
    'name' => 'type',
    'value' => '$data->getDay()', 
    'filter'=>CHtml::dropDownList(
        'work[day]',
        $work->day,
        $this->t(Work::$days),
        array('prompt'=>$this->t('All'),'class'=>'form-control'))
);
```

The option list is as following

```
Work::$days = array('weekday' => 'Weekday', 'weekend' => 'Weekend');
```

How can I use these two options to filter

```
array('Monday', 'Tuesday' ...);
```

Comment: do select the answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

You just need to look into 2 things

1. Your model name is `Work` not `work` and yii generates the fields related to form or filter input in the same format i.e `Modelname[fieldname]`.

   Its a good practice that if you are providing the name of the field manually and the field relates to active record you should use `Model::class` to print the class name rather than typing manually.
   Then pass empty as the selected value so that by default all records are displayed and the dropdown has the placeholder `All` selected
2. Are you saving the values in the database against the field `type` as **`Monday`** or **`monday`**.

   If its Monday then you have to change the `$days` array to `Work::$days=array('Monday'=>'Monday','Tuesday'=>'Tuesday')` otherwise its good t keep as it is.

So your column definition will look like below

```
array(
    'name' => 'type',
    'value' => '$data->getDay()', 
    'filter'=>CHtml::dropDownList(
        Work::class.'[name]',
        '',
        $this->t(Work::$days),
        array('prompt'=>$this->t('All'),'class'=>'form-control'))
);
```

Hope this starts working for you.